# Optimization of image resize process

Tags: c#, wpf, image, performance, optimization

I need to load several images (up to 1000) and display it in a list (longest side of the image max. 250 px).

Since many of them are raw format images (CR2 / AWR), I cannot open them simply by

```cs
var i = new Bitmap(x);
```

Therefore I am opening it as `BitmapImage`.

Secondly, size is really an issue, that's why I have to shrink it to a kind of thumbnail.
Since I cannot read the height and width during `BitmapImage` init process, I am loading it first, and then shrink it.

The following code does the trick, but it is awfully slow and consumes a hell of memory.
If I would ignore the "longest" side and shrink the width (or height) inside the init part, memory consumption is reduced to about 10 %.

Can somebody help me out to optimize it?

```cs
public BitmapSource getImage(string fileName, double width, double height)
{
    // Read and resize image
    BitmapImage tmpImage = new BitmapImage();

    tmpImage.BeginInit();
    tmpImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    tmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(fileName);
    tmpImage.EndInit();

    if (tmpImage.Width > tmpImage.Height)
    {
        tmpImage.DecodePixelWidth = (int)width;
    }
    else
    {
        tmpImage.DecodePixelHeight = (int)height;
    }

    return tmpImage;
}
```

Comment: am I understanding correctly?: 1. download image 2. resize image 3. display newly re-sized image

Comment: have you tried changing this `tmpImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;` to `tmpImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand;`? did it make any difference?

Comment: No, unfortunately, that makes no difference, neither in speed, nor memory usage

Comment: Be aware that setting DecodePixelWidth/Height after EndInit has no effect. It will simply be ignored. You have to set the properties before EndInit. In order to show images in a vertical ListBox, set DecodePixelWidth on all images to the same value, for a horizontal ListBox set DecodePixelHeight.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is, the user can choose if he wants to display it vertically or horizontally. I guess I will shrink it by height and for vertical listbox I will let the UI handle it.

Comment: If performance is of primary importance I would consider using some third-party library to open and re-scale the images. This might give you more control of speed vs quality. It may also make it easier to do it in the background and in parallel. Also consider caching if a image needs to be scaled more than once.